# Titanium ListView with TextField do an error in Android

Tags: android, forms, listview, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have to do a list of people.
This list have 2 fields, name and lastname.

I've created a listview, with a template like this :

```
                    <ListView id="partenairesList" defaultItemTemplate="template">
                        <Templates>
                            <ItemTemplate name="template">
                                <View class="textField-demi">
                                    <Label class="placeholder">Prénom</Label>
                                    <TextField bindId="field_name"></TextField>
                                    <View class="border-bottom textField-border"></View>
                                </View>
                                <View class="textField-demi textField-right">
                                    <Label class="placeholder">Nom</Label>
                                    <TextField bindId="field_lastname"></TextField>
                                    <View class="border-bottom textField-border"></View>
                                </View>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </Templates>
                        <ListSection id="partenairesListSection">
                        </ListSection>
                    </ListView>
```

This work on ios.
But when i add item in list on android, the app is killed with an error.

This is my function who add the item :

```
function addEmptyItemPartenaire(){
    $.partenairesListSection.appendItems([{
        template:'template',
        field_name:'',
        field_lastname:'',
    }]);
}
```

This is the console debug with errors :

```
[WARN] :   TiUIScrollView: (main) [137999,176598] Scroll direction could not be determined based on the provided view properties. Default VERTICAL scroll direction being used. Use the 'scrollType' property to explicitly set the scrolling direction.
[INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 15.674MB for 635812-byte allocation
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40aa9300)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [28953,205551] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap; Titanium 3.2.0,2013/12/20 10:57,d9182d6
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.listview.TiListViewTemplate.updateOrMergeWithDefaultProperties(TiListViewTemplate.java:231)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.listview.ListSectionProxy.processData(ListSectionProxy.java:432)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.listview.ListSectionProxy.handleAppendItems(ListSectionProxy.java:492)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.listview.ListSectionProxy.handleMessage(ListSectionProxy.java:236)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: This is not standard android sdk. sorry I cannot help. you should include titanium in your title

Comment: I have add Titanium in title, thx.

Comment: Where are you defining the 'template' at? And what doe sit look like?

Comment: My 'template' is defining in alloy xml view. Thx for your reply, i have found my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is caused by the item object data :

```
$.partenairesListSection.appendItems([{
    template:'template',
    field_name:'',
    field_lastname:'',
}]);
```

**"field_name"** and **"field_lastname"** are the bind id to my textfield.
So, for set a value, i need to give it an object with a "value" properties :

```
{
    template:'template',
    field_name:{value:''},
    field_lastname:{value:''},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `defaultItemTemplate="template"` from `ListView` and add `template="template"` in `ListSection`. Sometimes Android add random element to `ListView` it can not be handled by `defaultItemTemplate`

Additionaly you can create default template:

```
      <ItemTemplate name="defaultTemplate" height="0dp">
        <View height="0dp">
        </View>
      </ItemTemplate>
```